# Magento 1.9 captcha image not getting generated

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm on Magento 1.9 and currently facing an issue with the captcha on admin login page. Captcha image is not getting generated and it shows broken link in place of captcha image.

I also checked `webroot/media/captcha/admin` and `webroot/media/captcha/base` it is empty.

Can someone help me? How to go about troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check whether write permission is there for both these folders webroot/media/captcha/admin and webroot/media/captcha/base. So that the captcha image files can be created inside these folders.

Comment: What should be the ideal permission and the owner?

Comment: Ideal permission and the owner should be 775 and the owner is www-data.